# Prevent TableView Scrolls up after Core Data Insert

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data

Currently I've a Tableview that uses core data to populate it. The issue is that after I perform a Pull Down to Load more Old Messages, It inserts everything properly. But scrolls the TableView to the top. I'had been trying to avoid this. But don't know how.

Comment: check if you have used this method `- [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];` or `scrollRectToVisible`

Comment: @nilam this is whats happening. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwEW_jyuVX4

Answer (score 1):

When you reload a UITableView, entire table is reloaded not just its contents. 
For what solution you are seeking, you can:
1) store the visible first cell index in a variable.

```
NSArray *visible       = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSIndexPath *indexpath = (NSIndexPath*)[visible objectAtIndex:0];
```

2) reload the UITableView

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

3) scroll the table view to saved index.

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexpath 
             atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

This will work, but due to changes in the data due to reloading, it may vary by a cell or two.
Hope this helps u :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. but still with the same issue. here is my method http://pastie.org/10271126 with your code implemented

Comment: can you please print the index path stored in the first step?

Comment: when you start this method (fetchOldMessages), does your table have any previous data?

Comment: print the index path you get. and put a breakpoint n debug if it is executing the code or not. Clean your code first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82266/discussion-between-eddwinpaz-and-sana).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfVisibleRow
 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];